# Google Adsense moves whole page to the left

Tags: html, css, adsense

I added the google adsense code into my website on one page, what I noticed is that the whole page (inclusive Top navigation ec.) was shifted a little bit to the left after I added the code.

You especially notice this when you go from an page without the ad to the one with the ad.

So my problem is that I have no idea what could be the cause of this problem, neither do I know how to fix it.

Here the code:

HTML:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Botlane.net -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXX"
data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXX"></ins>
<script>
```

CSS:

```
.adsbygoogle {
    display:block;
    width:728px;
    height:90px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

(originally it was `display:inline-block`, but the change to `display:block` didn`t cause the problem, I tested this already)

Thanks for any help in advance

Edit:
Here are two screenshots of the Header, one while on the page with the ad, one while on a page without the ad. If you will compare them, you will notice a shift to left

[Header without Ad](http://gyazo.com/12d1badb29be2df01321f70fc20e6844)

[Header with Ad](http://gyazo.com/118168bcace1569388036769649989bd)

Comment: can u post an image to show us wat happens

Comment: Did an edit with two images of the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position shift is caused by the scroll bar appearing on the side. It is normal browser behaviour when the page becomes too long to fit in the window. You could add this to the body css to display the scroll bar all the time perhaps:

```
body {
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: At least I was first.

Answer (score 0):

It's the scrollbar that is added.
You can force the scrollbar with css:

```
html {
       overflow-y: scroll;
}
```